# How to specify/upgrade hermes-engine version?

Tags: react-native, react-native-hermes

### TLDR

After upgrading my ReactNative application to version `0.64.2`, app crash on launch. I'm aware that I need to upgrade/specify `hermes-engine` to `0.7.2`. Question is, where can I do this?

### Details

**Issue:**
After upgrading React Native to version `0.64.2` and create release type `.aab`, deploy app to Physical Device. App crash upon launch. Similar issue raised in Github and [solution was shared](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/31269#issuecomment-827140811) to upgrade hermes-engine version. Seems that, for 0.64.2 would require to specify to the specific `hermes-engine`, it would otherwise crash.

But where should I upgrade/specify the version?

### What I have tried

1. Manual specify the `hermes-engine` version `~0.7.2` at `node_modules/react-native/package.json` . Built `.aab` file, deploy to physical device. App launched as expected (no crash).

### As noted...

by RN team already in [their website](https://reactnative.dev/docs/hermes)[image]

by [RN Upgrade Helper](https://react-native-community.github.io/upgrade-helper/?from=0.63.2&to=0.64.2) [image]

Comment: For some reason, the crash issue no long occurs after I remove `node_modules` and `Pods` folders then reinstall them again. Might be some mistake on my project end, can't replicate this.